# PhP delete row from database onsubmit

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete a row of data from the data base, after a submit input is clicked.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   // sql to delete a record
$query = "DELETE * FROM wishList
     WHERE userID_FK = {$_SESSION['user_id']}
     AND itemName = {$row['itemName']}";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

if($result)
{
    echo 'Data Deleted';
}else{
    echo 'Data Not Deleted';
}

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Check the answer below. Might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove * from DELETE Query. If you get any other issue please let me know.

```
$query = "DELETE  FROM wishList
     WHERE userID_FK = {$_SESSION['user_id']}
     AND itemName = {$row['itemName']}";
```

Comment: This did not work. Thank you for your reply.